# Running a longer command from docker

Tags: bash, docker, zsh, dockerfile

I am using Docker to write a file on the fly and run it. The command looks like this so far (just to test the idea first):

```
docker run dockerfile/python cat <<EOF >hi.txt && tail hi.txt
> hi there
> EOF
```

For some reason this does not echo anything.

If I run this command without a HEREDOC then it does output the result. For example the following works:

```
docker run dockerfile/python cat > hi.txt && ls
hi.txt
```

How do I output the result of a multi line run command/HEREDOC.

Answer (score 9):

I was fiddling with [crossbuild](https://github.com/multiarch/crossbuild)*  and was wondering about how to use *here documents* to pipe commands to a Docker container. Here's the solution.

```
$ docker run --rm --interactive --volume $(pwd):/workdir --env CROSS_TRIPLE=x86_64-apple-darwin multiarch/crossbuild /bin/bash -s <<EOF
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
EOF
```

Quick rundown of what's happening.

- `--rm` tells Docker to remove the container when it finished execution, otherwise it would show up in the output `docker ps -a` (not mandatory to use of course)
- `--interactive`, `-i` is needed, otherwise `/bin/bash` would not run in an interactive environment and would not accept the here document from stdin as its input
- about the `-s` flag passed to `/bin/bash`

  > If the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain after option
  >   processing, then commands are read from the standard input.
- `--volume $(pwd):/workdir`, just `-v` will mount the current working directory on the host to `/workdir` in the container
- `--env CROSS_TRIPLE=x86_64-apple-darwin`, or simple `-e` tells the `crossbuild` container about the target platform and architecture (the container's entry point is `/usr/bin/crossbuild`, which is a shell script and based on the environment variable it's symlink the right toolchain components to the right places for the cross compilation to work)
- `multiarch/crossbuild` the name of the Docker container to run (available in Docker Hub)

The commands can be fed to Docker like this as well.

```
$ cat a.sh
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
$ docker run --rm -i -v $(pwd):/workdir -e CROSS_TRIPLE=x86_64-apple-darwin multiarch/crossbuild /bin/bash -s < a.sh
```

Hoped this helps.

## Update

Actually it seems you don't even need to use `/bin/bash -s`, it can be ommited, at least for the `crossbuild` container, YMMV.

<sub>*Linux based container used to produce multi-arch binaries: Linux, Windows and OS X, very cool.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I'm curious, what shell are you using so that the second command works? Because in bash the `hi.txt` is created on the host and so is the `ls`.

```
bash-3.2$ docker run --rm dockerfile/python cat > hi.txt && ls
Applications    Desktop     Documents   Downloads   Dropbox     Library     Movies      Music       Pictures    Public      VirtualBox VMs  hi.txt      projects
```

To achieve that, I'd have to use:

```
docker run --rm dockerfile/python bash -c 'cat > hi.txt && ls'
```

IMO, the simplest way to test stuff is to just use a container as a sandbox:

```
docker run -it dockerfile/python bash
```

And then just do stuff in that container's shell. Once I got things running well, I backport what I've done in a Dockerfile.