# docker run <IMAGE> <MULTIPLE COMMANDS>

Tags: docker, docker-image

I'm trying to run MULTIPLE commands like this.

```
docker run image cd /path/to/somewhere && python a.py
```

But this gives me "No such file or directory" error because it is interpreted as...

```
"docker run image cd /path/to/somewhere" && "python a.py"
```

It seems that some ESCAPE characters like "" or () are needed.

So I also tried

```
docker run image "cd /path/to/somewhere && python a.py"
docker run image (cd /path/to/somewhere && python a.py)
```

but these didn't work.

I have searched for [Docker Run Reference](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/) but have not find any hints about ESCAPE characters.

Comment: Note that for this particular use, `docker run` has a `-w/--workdir` argument.
`docker run -w /path/to/somewhere image python a.py`

Answer (score 587, accepted):

To run multiple commands in docker, use `/bin/bash -c` and semicolon `;`

```
docker run image_name /bin/bash -c "cd /path/to/somewhere; python a.py"
```

In case we need command2 (python) will be executed if and only if command1 (cd) returned zero (no error) exit status, use `&&` instead of `;`

```
docker run image_name /bin/bash -c "cd /path/to/somewhere && python a.py"
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint!
I simply tried [ docker run image "cd /bin; ls" ] and got following error messages.

[ exec: "cd /bin; ls": stat cd /bin; ls: no such file or directory ] [ Error response from daemon: Cannot start container ]

Comment: Anyone finds this answer might be interested in how to use here documents to feed commands to a container: [here's my answer to another question like this about here documents, feel free to check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35767573/433835).

Comment: `docker run alpine sh -c "ls | wc >> xxx"` this help me a lot, when bash is not available.

Comment: In case someone is facing troubles when using a command with  `$(...)` please have a look [here](https://serverfault.com/a/784225/411690)

Comment: This works for `cd` but not for things where return codes matter `;` is not the same as `&&` see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37069/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-chaining-commands

Comment: Thanks @NickZalutskiy, updated answer with your comment

Comment: Any simple solution to use the same along with passing parameters to the second command?

Comment: @anhlc Because the docker api for shell, golang and python have same functionality, how does those container native continuous integration service like drone-ci or gitlab-ci achieve this?

Comment: Nobody has mentioned that `docker run image_name /bin/bash -c` just appends a command to the entrypoint, and is not a silver bullet. Please check my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/75047712/20085654.

Answer (score 36):

You can do this a couple of ways:

1. Use the -w option to change the working directory:

   > -w, --workdir=""           Working directory inside the container

   https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-working-directory--w
2. Pass the entire argument to /bin/bash:

   ```
   docker run image /bin/bash -c "cd /path/to/somewhere; python a.py"
   ```

Answer (score 13):

You can also pipe commands inside Docker container, `bash -c "<command1> | <command2>"` for example:

```
docker run img /bin/bash -c "ls -1 | wc -l"
```

But, without invoking the shell in the remote the output will be redirected to the local terminal.

Answer (score 11):

`bash -c` works well if the commands you are running are relatively simple. However, if you're trying to run a long series of commands full of control characters, it can get complex.

I successfully got around this by piping my commands into the process from the outside, i.e.

`cat script.sh | docker run -i <image> /bin/bash`

Comment: You probably want to avoid the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 8):

Just to make a proper answer from the @Eddy Hernandez's comment and which is very correct since Alpine comes with ash not bash.

The question now referes to [Starting a shell in the Docker Alpine container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689628/starting-a-shell-in-the-docker-alpine-container) which implies using `sh` or `ash` or `/bin/sh` or `/bin/ash/`.

Based on the OP's question:

`docker run image sh -c "cd /path/to/somewhere && python a.py"`

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR;**

```
$ docker run --entrypoint /bin/sh image_name -c "command1 && command2 && command3"
```

**A concern regarding the accepted answer is below.**

Nobody has mentioned that `docker run image_name /bin/bash -c` just appends a command to the entrypoint. Some popular images are smart enough to process this correctly, but some are not.

Imagine the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
ENTRYPOINT ["echo"]
```

If you try building it as `echo` and running:

```
$ docker run echo /bin/sh -c date
```

You will get your command appended to the entrypoint, so that result would be `echo "/bin/sh -c date"`.

Instead, you need to override the entrypoint:

```
$ docker run --entrypoint /bin/sh echo -c date
```

[Docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options)

Comment: Excellent point!  Minor correction: your last `$ docker run ...` is missing `image_name`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to store the result in one file outside the container, in your local machine, you can do something like this.

```
RES_FILE=$(readlink -f /tmp/result.txt)

docker run --rm -v ${RES_FILE}:/result.txt img bash -c "grep root /etc/passwd > /result.txt"
```

The result of your commands will be available in `/tmp/result.txt` in your local machine.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who came here looking to do the same with `docker-compose` you just need to prepend `bash -c` and enclose multiple commands in quotes, joined together with `&&`.

So in the OPs example `docker-compose run image bash -c "cd /path/to/somewhere && python a.py"`

Comment: this one worked for me but the docker process exits after the command is executed

Comment: and how do I exit such a docker process? pressing ctrl C or ctrl Z or typing exit is not working or do I have to kill it by the docker stop command?

Comment: does `docker-compose down [service-name]` not work or? (and no worries you're welcome, happy to help :) )

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the commands running in a subshell, just put a set of outer parentheses around the multiple commands to run:

```
docker run image (cd /path/to/somewhere && python a.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it's not obvious, if `a.py` always needs to run in a particular directory, create a simple wrapper script which does the `cd` and then runs the script.

In your `Dockerfile`, replace

```
CMD [ 'python', 'a.py' ]
```

or whatever with

```
CMD [ '/wrapper' ]
```

and create a script `wrapper` in your root directory (or wherever it's convenient for you) with contents like

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
cd /path/to/somewhere
python a.py
```

In many situations, perhaps also consider rewriting `a.py` so that it doesn't need a wrapper. Either make it `os.chdir()` where it needs to be, or have it look for its data files in a directory you configure in its environment or similar.