# Starting a shell in the Docker Alpine container

Tags: linux, docker, containers, alpine-linux

To start an interactive shell for the Ubuntu image we can run:

```
ole@T:~$ docker run -it --rm ubuntu
root@1a6721e1fb64:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

But when this is run for the [Alpine Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/), the following results:

```
ole@T:~$ docker run -it --rm alpine
Error response from daemon: No command specified
```

What is the command for starting an interactive shell in an Alpine base container?

Answer (score 441, accepted):

```
ole@T:~$ docker run -it --rm alpine /bin/ash
(inside container) / #
```

Options used above:

- `/bin/ash` is Ash ([Almquist Shell](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ash/#busybox)) provided by BusyBox
- `--rm` Automatically remove the container when it exits (`docker run --help`)
- `-i` Interactive mode (Keep STDIN open even if not attached)
- `-t` Allocate a pseudo-TTY

Comment: Sure - good idea - ash is the shell and --rm removes the container after the run is complete.  So if you want the container to still be available after the run then skip usage of --rm.  I'm using it since I'm only experimenting ATM.

Comment: Then how to run it with detach property like ubuntu?

Comment: I believe in both cases ... Ubuntu or Alpine ... you just give it a `-d` option.

Comment: +1 for noting that Alpine has `ash` and not `bash`, which, not being very familiar with Alpine, is what got me and prevented me from accessing the container earlier.

Comment: If you are on RHEL and get permission denied error, it is SELinux again... gotta do that setenforce 0 temporarily :P

Answer (score 99):

Usually, an Alpine Linux image doesn't contain `bash`, Instead you can use `/bin/ash`, `/bin/sh`, `ash` or only `sh`.

/bin/ash

```
docker run -it --rm alpine /bin/ash
```

/bin/sh

```
docker run -it --rm alpine /bin/sh
```

ash

```
docker run -it --rm alpine ash
```

sh

```
docker run -it --rm alpine sh
```

I hope this information helps you.

Comment: What is the difference between `/bin/ash` and `ash`? Similar for `/bin/sh` and `sh`.

Comment: Hi @peter-mortensen, the difference is that  `ash` is only a symbolic link to  `/bin/ash`. Some linux distributions doesn't have symbolic links.

Answer (score 46):

Nowadays, Alpine images will boot directly into `/bin/sh` by default, without having to specify a shell to execute:

```
$ sudo docker run -it --rm alpine  
/ # echo $0  
/bin/sh
```

This is since the `alpine` image Dockerfiles now contain a [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) command, that specifies the shell to execute when the container starts:  `CMD ["/bin/sh"]`.

In older Alpine image versions (pre-2017), the CMD command was not used, since Docker used to create an additional layer for CMD which caused the image size to increase. This is something that the Alpine image developers wanted to avoid. In recent Docker versions (1.10+), CMD no longer occupies a layer, and so it was added to `alpine` images. Therefore, as long as CMD is not overridden, recent Alpine images will boot into `/bin/sh`.

For reference, see the following commit to the official Alpine Dockerfiles by Glider Labs:
https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/commit/ddc19dd95ceb3584ced58be0b8d7e9169d04c7a3#diff-db3dfdee92c17cf53a96578d4900cb5b

Answer (score 40):

In case the container is already running:

```
docker exec -it container_id_or_name ash
```