# How to exec into a docker container when the image was created with dockerfile-maven-plugin?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I'm creating docker images using `dockerfile-maven-plugin` and I want to shell into the container, and I'm getting this error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown
```

I've tried:

- docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash
- docker exec -it <container_id> bash

both with the same result

this is how I'm running the image:

```
docker run <image_id>
```

this is how I'm creating the image:

```
mvn install dockerfile:build
```

build on pom.xml:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I expect to open a shell into the container

Comment: The error is explicit, “bash” doesn’t exist in the container. What is your base image? Post a copy of the Dockerfile you’re building the image from maybe(?).

Comment: sure:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","hello.Application"]
```

Comment: should I be able to add this to the original post ?

Comment: You should be able to update your question, yes. Ref. your Dockerfile you’re building off an alpine image, they don’t contain bash in most cases, could use e.g. “sh” or “ash”. Check this question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35689628/1423507

Comment: Also, docker exec requires the container that you’re executing the command in, ref. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/ - Usage: docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]

Comment: @masseyb thanks for your answer, docker run -it --rm  0d73f8db9e99 /bin/ash as suggested in the other question does not work either. any other ideas ?

Comment: docker exec is to execute a command in an already running container cf. docker run to run a new container instance - if you’re container is running then you should use docker exec -it ...

Comment: awesome !! docker exec -it  <container_id> /bin/ash worked. thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

as I'm building off an alpine image, the correct command is

```
docker exec -it  <container_id> /bin/ash
```