# Run inline command with pipe in docker container

Tags: bash, docker, pipe, command-line-interface

I want to run a set of commands in a docker container, e.g.:

```
docker run -i <image> cmd1 | cmd2
```

Both `cmd1` and `cmd2` should be run inside the container.

Is it possible? If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: "I would like to have my pipe not saved on the docker container since I'm only saving the inline command in an external bash script." - It's really not clear what this means.  From context, my best guess is that you're asking how to ensure that both `cmd1` and `cmd2` are executed *inside* the container - is that correct?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yes, I'll update the question accordingly, thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490874/docker-run-image-multiple-commands

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth it works, but environment variables are missing. If you want you can put it as an answer (if you also know how to solve for env variables, better).

Comment: Which environment variables?  AFAIK this question is a duplicate of the linked question, so normally I'd vote to close as such.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth you are right, let's close it.