# How to override cmd in docker?

Tags: docker

I have dockerfile

```
CMD [ "/run/myfile.sh" ]
```

I build it

```
docker build . -t myRepo/test/my-app:1.0.0
```

and run it

```
docker run -it --rm myRepo/test/my-app:1.0.0 sh
```

If I want to change the CMD with more parameters 
How I can do it ?
for example I want to create folder

```
   command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: [ "-c", "mkdir -p /myfolder/sub && mkdir -p /myfolder2/sub2"]
```

I tried

```
docker run -it --rm myRepo/test/my-app:1.0.0 sh [ "-c", "mkdir -p /myfolder/sub && mkdir -p /myfolder2/sub2"]
```

Comment: You already overrode the value of `CMD` with the `sh` at the end of your `docker run` command. JSON syntax doesn't work on the command line, just enter it as you would on the command line, same as if you weren't in a container.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker run <IMAGE> <MULTIPLE COMMANDS>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490874/docker-run-image-multiple-commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to run multiple commands, try to use entrypoint.sh

Just create a shell script, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p /foo/bar
mkdir -p /foo2/bar2
#whatever
```

And edit your Dockerfile:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

But I'm not sure it's your case, creating directories are better in `RUN` commands, not `CMD`:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN mkdir -p /foo/bar/ && mkdir -p /foo2/bar2/
RUN ...
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]
```