# How to submit multiple commands to AWS Batch using Boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-batch

I'm trying to run multiple shell commands through Docker using AWS Batch and boto3. When I try to submit multiple commands using the & sign as follows, the job fails.

**My attempt**

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client("batch")
response = client.submit_job(
    jobName='AndrewJob',
    jobQueue='AndrewJobQueue',
    jobDefinition='AndrewJobDefinition',
    containerOverrides={
        'command': 'ls & python myjob.py'.split(),
    },
    timeout = {'attemptDurationSeconds': 100}
)
print(response)
```

The error is:

> ls: cannot access '&': No such file or directory

According to the Docker Docs here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd and this post here [docker run <IMAGE> <MULTIPLE COMMANDS>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490874/docker-run-image-multiple-commands) it seems like this should be possible in shell form.

Comment: have you tried `&&`?

Comment: @badger0053 - yes, I've tried && and get the same error (but with '&&')

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Batch is behaving like `subprocess.Popen` in that it executes the command as one command where the first argument is the command name and the remaining arguments are the command arguments. I got this to work with `subprocess.Popen`, so I bet it would work with Batch:

```py
subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", "ls && echo \"Hello world\""])
```

Comment: I affirm that simply "cmd1 && cmd2" will not work, even if this could be run as a **docker run** command (the AWS Batch Guide would indicate otherwise). The `command` argument I needed to pass through the Job Definition creation followed the json format ["/bin/bash", "-c", "command1; command2"]