# Why do I need to specify `/bin/bash -c` when I already have SHELL ["bash", "-c"] in the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, shell

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490874/docker-run-image-multiple-commands), in order to `docker-run` multiple commands, I need

```
docker run image_name /bin/bash -c "cd /path/to/somewhere; python a.py"
```

However, I can specify the default shell in the `Dockerfile` with the [`SHELL`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell) instruction.  So given that I can already specify the default shell of a container, why is it necessary to specify again with `/bin/bash -c` when running the docker container?  What was the rationale behind not automatically using the shell specified with the `SHELL` instruction?

Comment: Not all docker images *have* a shell installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `SHELL` instruction in the `Dockerfile` is **only** used for the `Dockerfile` `RUN` instructions (done during image creation)

`docker run` is a completely different command (it creates a container and run a command in it). The command you specify after the image name depends on the way the image is built. Some containers allow to run arbitrary command and also `/bin/bash` (if installed).

The default command is specify within you docker file with the `Dockerfile` `CMD` instruction. It default to empty.

You can also specify an `ENTRYPOINT` instruction that will run the `CMD`. The default is `/bin/sh`.

Comment: This shell will active not only during building, but also in image too: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7281#issuecomment-389440503